# Function behaves differently when run on Windows or Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, console, codeblocks

I have a simple function that prints lines of text to the console, centered, with empty space filled in with an '=' sign. When I run this function with my program on Linux I see the text displayed properly at the top of the console window followed by the menu prompt from my program, but on Windows it prints nothing and skips directly to the menu prompt. Both programs are compiled and run in codeblocks using GNU gcc with -std=c++11.

```
void _print_center(vector<string>& tocenter)
{
    int center;
    for ( int x; x<static_cast<int>(tocenter.size());x++ )
    {
        char sfill = '=';
        string line = tocenter[x];
        center = (68/2)-(tocenter[x].length()/2);
        line.replace(0, 0, center, sfill);
        cout << std::left << std::setfill(sfill);
        cout << std::setw(68) << line << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int x` is not initialized. You're relying on undefined behavior here, which could theoretically do anything (such as wipe humanity off the face of this planet).

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Thank-you! That did the trick. And you're right: I should always initialize my variables before attempting to use them. I'm really surprised this was working on _any_ system!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got an answer to your question (uninitialized variables). I recommend that you untangle and simplify your code so that this kind of issues don't creep up as often. For example:

Create a function that centers a single string.

```
void center( std::ostream& os, const std::string& text, int width ) {
  if ( text.size() >= width ) {
    // Nothing to center, just print the text.
    os << text << std::endl;
  } else {
    // Total whitespace to pad.
    auto to_pad = width - text.size();
    // Pad half on the left
    auto left_padding = to_pad / 2;
    // And half on the right (account for uneven numbers)
    auto right_padding = to_pad - left_padding;

    // Print the concatenated strings. The string constructor will
    // correctly handle a padding of zero (it will print zero `=`).
    os << std::string( left_padding, '=' ) 
       << text
       << std::string( right_padding, '=' )
       << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Once you've tested that the function works well for a single string, it is trivial to rely on C++ to apply it to a vector of strings:

```
void center( std::ostream& os,
             const std::vector< std::string >& strings,
             int width ) {
  for ( auto&& string : strings ) {
    center( os, string, width );
  }
}
```

Whether you want to use `std::string`, or `iomanip` manipulators, or `std::setfill` the point remains the same: do not implement "iteration and formating" in the same function.

Comment: Marked as answer, but this does leave me with more questions. Specifically about your use of auto. I am not really sure how to use this type, or whether I can rely on it. Example: If `auto num;` then accidentally assign a `string` or `char` to it, what will happen later when I attempt to change the value with an `int`? Additionally, I have no idea what the `for ( auto&& string : strings )` is. Is that like passing by reference, or something else entirely?

Comment: About the answer: does `text.size()` when used on a string work the same as `text.length()`? For a vector `text.size()` will give the number of elements, while `text[x].length()` will give the length of the string at that point in the vector.

Comment: Sorry about using so many relatively novel features: finger memory. You correctly assume that `auto` is not always a good idea, but I find that it does what it is supposed to do most of the time. For your specific question: you cannot do simply `auto num;` and then assign whatever you want to it (C++ is a *statically compiled* language; all types must be known at compile time). What you can do is `auto x = 1;`, and `x` is an int: no questions there.

Comment: Regarding the second question:  `auto &&` will accomplish two things. First, it will not make a copy (it will instead take a reference). Second, it will correctly derive the `const-`ness (get me an immutable reference). I use it everywhere unless I am positive that I need a mutable reference or a copy.

Comment: In c++11, `text.size()` and `text.length()` are synonyms (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size)

Comment: One more thing before I make this sound like 20 questions. What kind of a for loop is `for ( auto&& string : stirngs )` is that somewhat like string comprehensions in python, or more of a ternary operator in a loop, or something else entirely.

Comment: It is a “for each element in a container”.

Comment: @AlexanderMeyers `for( type a : types b )` is a for each loop. It is a short hand for this: `for ( std::size_t n = 0; n < container.size(); n++ ) { do something to each n in v; }` instead of that you can simply do `for( auto&& n : container ) { do something to each n in v; }` This works with containers that have a `begin` and `end` iterator.

Comment: @FrancisCugler So this would work on a `string` as well? I have seen that you can use `text.begin()` and `text.end()` on them. Like if I wanted to split a string on a character like `','` this would be a good shorthand for setting up the loop.

Comment: Yes. It would iterate character by character. Read the docs for range for and, most importantly, <algorithm>. You’ll be a much better C++ programmer for it.

Comment: @FrancisCugler,@Escualo Thanks a lot, and I will go read those docs. I just sometimes need to have things explained in more than one way before they become concrete for me.

Comment: Of course. It takes a very long time to master this stuff (I have not, after almost a decade of professional experience). The best investment of one hour of your time could be watching Sean Parent’s talk “C++ Seasoning” (google it).

Comment: I have absolutely no professional experience nor training (college courses) in programming of any kind especially C++. I am self taught and have been since around 2003. I learned the hard way through text based online tutorials with very little feedback and tons of hours of trial and error and tons of hours of learning how to debug! If you can master how to efficiently debug a program that is over 1/2 of your battle and the rest will come to you almost naturally. I've pushed my self to even learn 3D Graphics Programming in DirectX & OpenGL. Now I'm learning Vulkan. You never stop learning.